# Can not delete comments in quick succession

Tags: bug

I have had a few times where I have gone to delete several comments on a single post to help remove some of the irrelevant comments. The first comment deletes fine, but it takes several seconds before I can delete another comment.

When I hit the x on the second comment I get the box asking if I really want to delete the comment, I say yes, but then nothing happens.

Comment: I bet it's related to the same functionality that prevents you from voting on more than one comment every 5 seconds. The SE team probably forgot to code in the same notification for other rapid comment actions like successive deletes, or a vote followed rapidly by a delete.